# Injections without fixed-points and the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following statement in $\sf ZF$:

> (I) Whenever $X$ is a set with more than $1$ element, there is an injective map $\iota: X\to X$ such that $\iota(x) \neq x$ for all $x\in X$.

The [Axiom of Choice (AC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) implies (I) -- but does (I) imply (AC)?

Comment: Having $|X|=|X|+|X|$ for infinite sets should be enough for (I). This was mentioned in comments to this answer: [Existence of a bijective function with no fixed points](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66922#66933). This post seems a bit related, too: [Is it consistent without the axiom of choice that every permutation of some infinite set have fixed points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1270419)

Comment: You may be interested in Howard-Rubin's book "Consequences of the Axiom of Choice". The particular statement you ask about doesn't appear there, but it shouldn't be hard for you to find a form which implies it (e.g. Form 3 which is the statement mentioned by Martin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is shown in

Tachtsis, E.
On the existence of permutations of infinite sets without fixed points in set theory without choice.
Acta Math. Hungar. 157 (2019), no. 2, 281-300.

that ZF+(every infinite set supports a permutation with no fixed points)
does not imply AC. It is easy to see in ZF that a finite set supports a cyclic permutation, so that should be sufficient for your question.

Comment: I mean, yes. But it's an easy consequence of Sageev's work from the late 60s/early 70s that is mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: My original answer gave the bib info for Sageev's paper, but I edited my answer to point to the paper that answers the question asked on this page.

Comment: My point is that saying "it was shown in..." and referring to anything but Sageev's paper is a bit odd. It's as though you'd refer to a paper from 2022 proving that the axiom of choice is equivalent to "in a partial order where every chain has a lower bound, below every element there is a minimal element".